# How to code my data by using Richardson Extrapolation?

Tags: numerical-integration

[image]

The cardiac output of this patient can be calculated using the Stewart Hamilton equation. To do this, we will first use the Trapezoidal Rule to find the value of the concentrations (C(t)),I1,I2 and I3 for three different step sizes, h1=2,h2=4,h3=8. After that, we will use these values to further use Richardson Extrapolation and find our final value of C(t). So, my problem is, I dont have idea to do the coding by using the Richardson Extrapolation.

```
ynewdata1 = Table[ydata[[4 i - 3]], {i, 4}];
NewSum1 = ynewdata1[[1]];
Do[NewSum1 = NewSum1 + ynewdata1[[i]], {i, 2, Length[ynewdata1]}];
NewSum1;
I1 = (h3/2)*(ydata[[1]] + 2*NewSum1 + ydata[[17]])

ynewdata = Table[ydata[[2 i - 1]], {i, 8}];
NewSum = ynewdata[[1]];
Do[NewSum = NewSum + ynewdata[[i]], {i, 2, Length[ynewdata]}];
NewSum;
I2 = (h2/2)*(ydata[[1]] + 2*NewSum + ydata[[17]])

    xdata = Array[# &, 17, {5, 37}];
ydata = {0, 0, 0.1, 0.11, 0.4, 4.1, 9.1, 8, 4.2, 2.3, 1.1, 0.9, 1.75, 
   2.06, 2.25, 2.32, 2.43};
n = Length[xdata];
h = xdata[[n]] - xdata[[n - 1]];
h1 = h;
h2 = 2*h;
h3 = 2*h2;
sum = 0;
For[i = 1, i < n, i++,
 {sum += 2*ydata[[i]];}]
I3 = (h1/2)*(ydata[[1]] + sum + ydata[[17]])
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Have you experimented with the [RichardsonExtrapolate](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RichardsonExtrapolate/) function at the repository?

Comment: As far as I know, Richardson Extrapolation is a method to accelerate the convergence of a converging sequence. However, your conentration C[t] is a function of t . Does it converge to some constant value?

Comment: I don't have any experience by using the RichardsonExtrapolate function.

Comment: Yes, it does converge to some constant value

Comment: Richardson extrapolation appears in several posts on this site. You can search the site for them.